# delete the gradient of smart diagram

Tags: beamer, smartdiagram

I would like to take out the color gradient of my diagram, I tried using this method but it didn't work out. I am still getting this result. 
Is it possible also to fix their size to the same one please?

```
   \tikzset{
        every shadow/.style={
            fill=none,
            shadow xshift=0pt,
            shadow yshift=0pt}
    }
    \tikzset{module/.append style={top color=\col,bottom color=\col}}
    \smartdiagramset{
        set color list={red!40, Cerulean!35,yellow,green}}
    \smartdiagram[descriptive diagram]{
        {Models,{Choose the electrical sources models}},
        {Sizing, {Define a sizing module able to desgin an infrastructure based on 
                \begin{itemize}
                    \item [--] meterological data
                    \item  [--] load
        \end{itemize}}},
        {Management, Define a management module able to provide an optimal power profile for each step of the negotiation},
        {Validation, Experiment these both modules to ensure the reliability of the system}}
```

[image]

Comment: Please try to reword your question such that it becomes understandable. Do you want to remove the color gradient/shading? Also your code is far from compilable with colors like `Cerulean` or `\couleurModule`.

Comment: sorry, I forgot to add the color of the commands created. But it's not the colors the problem, Its the gradation of the color to the white..

Comment: You need to use `description`, i.e. `\tikzset{description/.append style={top color=\col,bottom color=\col}}`, not `module`. If you want to remove the color gradient from the circles as well, use `\tikzset{description/.append style={top color=\col,bottom color=\col},
 description title/.append style={top color=\col,bottom color=\col}}`.

Comment: It's working ! perfect and if I would like to fix their size ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are now a couple of things so I decided to write an answer. First of all, you need to change the styles of the appropriate elements. Rather than `module` for a `descriptive diagram` these are `description` and `description title`. To synchronize their sizes, you can add an appropriate `minimum height`, and then you also need to increase the `descriptive items y sep`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{no shadow/.style={
     every shadow/.style={
         fill=none,
         shadow xshift=0pt,
         shadow yshift=0pt}
 }}
 \tikzset{description/.append style={top color=\col,bottom color=\col,
 minimum height=6.5em,no shadow},
 description title/.append style={top color=\col,bottom color=\col,
 minimum height=6.5em,no shadow}}
 \smartdiagramset{descriptive items y sep=7em,
     set color list={red!40,blue!35,orange!40,cyan!50}}
 \smartdiagram[descriptive diagram]{
     {Models,{Choose the electrical sources models}},
     {Sizing, {Define a sizing module able to desgin an infrastructure based on 
             \begin{itemize}
                 \item [--] meterological data
                 \item  [--] load
     \end{itemize}}},
     {Management, Define a management module able to provide an optimal power profile for each step of the negotiation},
     {Validation, Experiment these both modules to ensure the reliability of the system}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Since you did not provide a complete MWE, I didn't have your colors and had to make some colors up.